# Can the application of logically equivalent “if-then” expressions in stimulus-response processes yield meaningful results?

Tags: logic

Can the application of logically equivalent “if-then” expressions in stimulus-response processes yield meaningful results in finding alternative stimulus-response paths, or do such expressions only describe the same path?

Comment: What does "applying [an expression]" in "stimulus-response processes" mean? There's no context for this question, and the reason for the tag "boolean algebra" is not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not meaningful in general.  "If I fly to the moon tonight then the Russians won World War II." is logically equivalent to "If I have 3 quarters then I have 75 cents."  I have heard of a branch of logic called 'relevance logic' that does not allow such jibberish, but I have not personally explored it.
   You can probably construct a strong argument by writing your premises or antecedents and then stating what follows from them.  It wouldn't be deductive, but it could be more powerful.